# How to list all files inside the folder of sharepoint using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, office365

I'm currently using shareplum and was able to do the download thing using this code below:

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version
import csv


authcookie = Office365('https://bboxxeng.sharepoint.com/', username='---', password='---').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://bboxxeng.sharepoint.com/sites/TESTIAN', version=Version.v2016, authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder('Shared%20Documents/Test')
data = folder.get_file('Office ss E1.csv')
with open('asas.csv', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(data)
   f.close()
```

I tried using `list_data = sp_list.GetListItems()` but have no luck extracting the file names, I've also ready and tried googling but still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I understand you want to list all files in a folder so that you can download or do other modification via the file name. If so, you can get it via below attrbutes:

[files](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/objects.html#files)

```
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/test')

allfiles= folder.files

print(allfiles)
```

[image]

////////////  Updated //////

The result contains file name and other properties.

[image]

For example, i want to get the name of first file from the returned result.

```
allfiles= folder.files
demofile= allfiles[0]
print(demofile['Name'])
```

Comment: Hi @baker,

Thank you for your response.
But what if I just want to have the file name

Comment: 'folder.files' actually returns JSON array as response. There is a field 'Name' which contains the file name. So have to parse JSON to get the file name.